# Maintaining justification of justified inline-block elements after manipulation using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, dom, text-align

I am using text-align:justify to evenly space out inline-block elements.  I am using jQuery to swap certain elements around so they fit better (eg fill the rows more efficiently).  However the browser no longer justifies the swapped elements correctly.  Is there any way to make the browser re-justify elements to overcome this problem?

**edit**
Here is a jsfiddle showing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/sprintstar/HKDd9/3/

Comment: please jsfiddle your code or post some html and css which you have used.

Comment: Attempted to recreate your issue here http://jsfiddle.net/2kWSk/, but the divs appear to keep their text alignment after swapping. Perhaps in your case after swapping positions they no longer match CSS properties that they did before? A link to a fiddle would help identify the problem though.

Comment: This http://jsfiddle.net/sprintstar/HKDd9/1/ should demonstrate what i am trying to do (although I can't actually get the elements to swap).

Comment: Ah here we go: http://jsfiddle.net/sprintstar/HKDd9/2/

Comment: Elements still not swapping, but it shows the loss of justification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in a missing space between inline-block elements. What you miss is the text node:

```
$(function() {
    var eq3 = $('.container a:eq(3)');
    var eq4 = $('.container a:eq(4)');
    eq4.before(eq3).before(" ");
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/archatas/HKDd9/4/

Comment: do you mean: eq3.before(eq4).before(" ");

Comment: I didn't check this actual code, but making sure there is a space between my manipulated elements was the key to keeping it all working..

Answer (score 0):

I have a possible solution though I am not sure about the reason why your code is not working as intended. Maybe someone could shed some light on the issue.

First of all `eq4.before(eq3);` means you are placing it back where you picked it. I believe you meant `eq4.insertBefore(eq3);`

I tried adding a new element and it worked perfectly

```
 $('<a href="#" class="sq-1"><img src="http://placehold.it/64x32" /></a>').insertBefore(eq3);
```

Edit:
 But cloning the same element is not producing the same result.

```
eq4.clone().insertBefore(eq3);
eq4.remove();
```

Comment: You're right, insertBefore is what I needed, I have updated the jsfiddle link in my question, so now the elements are swapping, but no longer justified.

Comment: Your `eq4.clone().insertBefore(eq3).remove();` line doesn't seem to work?